glfw multi windowing doesn't work properly
I am trying to make an API on top of the glfw API using cpp
and I want to be able to create multiple windows, when I create two windows, and change the context between them so i can render on both of them, and they work exactly like I want, but if one of the windows gets minized or scale the other to cover the screen
the other window stops responding as if the window stops pulling events.
Here is an example of the code:
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main() {
    // Initialize GLFW
    if (!glfwInit()) {
        // Initialization failed
        return -1;
    }

    // Create the first window and its OpenGL context
    GLFWwindow* window1 = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Window 1", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window1) {
        // Window or context creation failed
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window1);

    // Create the second window and its OpenGL context
    GLFWwindow* window2 = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Window 2", NULL, NULL);

    if (!window2) {
        // Window or context creation failed
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    // Main loop
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window1) && !glfwWindowShouldClose(window2)) {

        // Make the first window's context current
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window1)

        // Render to the first window
        // Swap buffers and poll events for the first window
        glfwSwapBuffers(window1);

        glfwPollEvents();

        // Make the second window's context current
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window2);

        // Render to the second window
        // Swap buffers and poll events for the second window
        glfwSwapBuffers(window2);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    // Cleanup
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

I was trying to use the the stuff related to window focus in glfw but I didn't know what to do

Can you remove every second (every blank) line  in your code to make it better readable?

OpenGL is single-output, it only have a single context.

@Some programmer dude i don't think you understand this, i know opengl is a single-output, but this code is an example of my code, bc it have the same problem, my original code renders fine with two windows
